# Can we get Pandas to stop with the pd.NA?

Tags: pandas, boolean, typeerror, na

With a recent re-install of python on my computer, I began getting the error TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous. My dataframes now have null values of NA rather than None or NaN. This is causing major issues in my scripts as many of my conditional statements and methods to subset dataframes now return this error. I have had some luck using fillna() from this post, but this is not efficient as I have to define a function and then call it repeatedly throughout each script. Certain situations will also cause this fillna function to not work as intended.

Is there any way to change Pandas' behavior to treat null values as it used to? I'm wondering if there is a magic command or some configuration setting I can use to make it revert to using None or NaN. I am using Pandas 1.4.4.

An example of when the pd.NA stops my script:

File "C:\Users\tsizemore\AppData\Local\Temp\2\ipykernel_17900\3126683403.py", line 5, in <cell line: 3>
start_row = oid_subset[oid_subset.UTM_N == max(oid_subset.UTM_N)]

File "pandas_libs\missing.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.missing.NAType.**bool**

TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous

I have defined this function to remove , but it doesn't always work and must be called repeatedly:

```
def remove_na(df):
    """
    Remove <NA> values from dataframe that aren't JSON serializeable and 
    cause other issues
    """
    # get rid of the <NA> values which aren't json serializable
    for column in df.columns:
        try:
            df[column].fillna('', inplace=True)
        except:
            try:
                df[column].fillna(numpy.nan, inplace=True)
            except:
                df[column].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

However note that '' is actually Null